# css :after линия

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
мне нужно чтобы была только одна линия :after... почему их две?

```
.cactus-style-top-line :after, .cactus-style-top-line-full :after  {
    bottom: auto;
    background-color: rgba(179,181,182,0.32);
}

.cactus-style-solid-bg :after, .cactus-style-bottom-line-full :after, .cactus-style-top-line-full :after {
    padding: 0 1000px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 1000px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 1000px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
}

.cactus-top-bar :after, .cactus-navigation :after {
  display:block;  
  position: absolute;
   bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    min-height: 1px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Ответ: потому что...А если серьезно то,что Вы указали выше css,не дает возможности воспроизвести эти две линии

Comment: Но они есть....

Comment: @Oleksii, добавьте `HTML` в пример